# Concurrent queue removing item outs of synch or reordering

Tags: c#, concurrency

I need to be able to reorder or remove items from a queue that will have items added to by one task and be monitored and items taken off by another.  The program is currrently using the Dataflow library and I was wondering if anyone has any experience and can please give insights or examples on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the specifics of the library you're using, the task you are working on is not sound, since reorder is a global task that can be completed only when all elements are available.

There are concurrent ways of ordering arrays and lists, mergeSort for instance is really scalable with a concurrent model, but the elements need to be all available when the ordering starts.

On the other hand, you can keep a partial list ordered by doing precise insertions on a growing data structure as the elements become available to the ordering process.

So, I would use the queue only as a buffer, a way for the producer task to send elements asynchronously to the ordering task. The ordering task then keeps another structure, most likely a double linked list or some other strongly connected structure that gives good performance on insertions, and uses it to add the new elements in the right position as soon as they become available in the queue (taking them out of the queue).